# how to resolve following easyrtc issue?

Tags: node.js, express, webrtc, easyrtc

I've written following code:

```
var http    = require("http");              // http server core module
var express = require("express");           // web framework external module
var io      = require("socket.io");         // web socket external module
var easyrtc = require("easyrtc");           // EasyRTC external module
var app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'));

io= io.listen(server,{"log level":1});
var rtc = easyrtc.listen(server, io);
```

this is giving following error:

> $node server info    - EasyRTC: Starting EasyRTC Server (v1.0.10) on
>   Node (v0.10.26) [TypeError: Object # has no method 'get']
>   TypeError: Object # has no method 'get'
>       at async.waterfall.pub.socketServer.sockets.on.easyrtcid (/home/ritzy1/Downloads/downloaded
>   codes/VEDIO/change2/testexpandwb/node_modules/easyrtc/lib/easyrtc_default_event_listeners.js:1472:29)
>       at fn (/home/ritzy1/Downloads/downloaded codes/VEDIO/change2/testexpandwb/node_modules/easyrtc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:582:34)
>       at Object._onImmediate (/home/ritzy1/Downloads/downloaded codes/VEDIO/change2/testexpandwb/node_modules/easyrtc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:498:34)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)

Ηow can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a specific port number in the listen() function.
Change the following line 
 `var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'));` 
with 
 `var server = http.createServer(app).listen(8080);` 
Note : 8080 is a port number you can specify any other port number which are not currently using.

Happy coding